# How can I extract certain words from a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example I have the following:

```
78-Inch 2160p 3D Curved 4K Smart TV
```

I want to only extract certain words from this:

```
Curved
4K
```

Also I want to extract the size which changes for different models, in this case 78-Inch or 78 Inch

I want to string them all together as such:

```
78-Inch Curved 4K
```

What function would I use in Javascript to do this?

Note: I know little to nothing about Javascript but a program I use needs me to use some javascript functions.

Thanks!

Comment: RTFM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I'm assuming **`string` is your string**.

```
var words = ["78-Inch", "Curved", "4K"],
    new_string = string.split(' ').filter(function (a) {
        return words.indexOf(a) > -1;
    }).join(' ');
```

### How it works

This isn't that complicated once you wrap your head around it. First, we define the works we want to keep in the `words` array *(keep in mind, each work is separated by a space)*. Then we split the string up into its *words* by `.split(' ')`. The next part is `.filter()`. This go through each work and check if it is in out array. If it isn't, it will remove it. After filtering, It will join all the words with a space.